# Webpack: css-loader not resolving url

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, webpack, css-loader

I am getting the below error when trying to use an image (background-image: url('path_to_image')) in my sass file under src directory. However, I am able to call the same file from index.js. I am not sure what is missing in my Webpack config.

Error

ERROR in ./src/sass/main.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/sass/main.scss) Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../img/hero-small.jpg'

Folder structure

```
dist
  js
  public
     css
     images

src
  img
  js
  sass
  index.js
```

Code where her-small.jpg is being called from

source directory structure in closer detail:

```
img
sass
  components
     header.scss
```

within the header.scss, I am calling

```
background-image: url("../../img/hero-small.jpg");
```

Also, the output build css is showing the same path

```
background-image: url("../../img/hero-small.jpg");
```

package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.16.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  }
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/js/index.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'js/bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: './src/index.html'
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('./public/css/main.css')
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test:/\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use:[{
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {presets:['es2015']}
                }]
        }, {
                test:/\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({fallback:'style-loader',use:['css-loader','sass-loader']})
            },
            {
                test:/\.(png|svg|jp(e*)g|gif)$/,
                exclude:/node_modules/,
                use:[{
                    loader: "file-loader",
                    options: {
                        name:'[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath:'./public/images'
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

UPDATE

Based on this post, I have included one more loader:resolve-url-loader and set the options of css-loader for url to false.

use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({fallback:'style-loader',use:[{loader:'css-loader',options:{url:false}},'resolve-url-loader','sass-loader']})
upon further research, I found the issues described on sass-loader github page:

Since Sass/libsass does not provide url rewriting, all linked assets must be relative to the output. If you're just generating CSS without passing it to the css-loader, it must be relative to your web root. If you pass the generated CSS on to the css-loader, all urls must be relative to the entry-file (e.g. main.scss). More likely you will be disrupted by this second issue. It is natural to expect relative references to be resolved against the .scss file in which they are specified (like in regular .css files). Thankfully there are a two solutions to this problem: Add the missing url rewriting using the resolve-url-loader. Place it before the sass-loader in the loader chain. Library authors usually provide a variable to modify the asset path. bootstrap-sass for example has an $icon-font-path.

use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({fallback:'style-loader',use:[{loader:'css-loader',options:{url:false}},'resolve-url-loader','sass-loader']})
After adding the above changes, build passes but the final url in my output dist folder is the same as the path I provided in the source folder (../../img/hero.jpg) which is resulting in a bad path.

As a temporary solution:

I have imported the images to my index.js file and let the file-loader load the images from my src directory to the dist/public/images directory.
I referred the images in main.sass from dist/public/images hoping it will be available.
Although it was not a fool proof solution, I hope that there's already a much easier solution that I am not aware of. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code where hero-small.jpg is referenced?

Comment: Hi Carter - I have updated the code above with the image reference.

Comment: At the point where the style rule is applied, is it two hops up the directory tree to get to img folder?   ../../ = two hops up.  Have you tried changing that or do you have another example where the reference works properly?

Comment: I was finally able to resolve it by adding few options

1. add publicPath to ExtractTextPlugin (../..)
2. Add sourceMap: true option to css-loader,sass-loader
3. Add     devtool: 'source-map' to webpack config. 

After adding the 3 options above, the path resolved to url(../../public/images/hero-small.jpg) in the bundled css file.